# Magento2 - Sample Download for custom Import

Tags: magento2

Hi i am trying to add a custom import fucntionality for my module but I got this error:-

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getUrl() on
>   null in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\m2\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php:775
>   Stack trace: #0
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\m2\vendor\magento\module-backend\Block\Widget\Tabs.php(141):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->getUrl() #1 [internal
>   function]: Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tabs->addTab('importpincode',
>   'netsmartz_pinco...') #2
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\m2\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block.php(298):
>   call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #3
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\m2\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block.php(169):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->generateAction(Object(Netsmartz\PincodeChecker\Block\Adminhtml\Importpincode\Edit\Tabs),
>   'addTab', Array) #4
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\m2\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool.php(81):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context)) #5
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\m2\ve in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\m2\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php
>   on line 775

here is my code:-

```
<?php

namespace vendor\module\Block\Adminhtml\Importpincode\Edit\Tab;

class Importpincode extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic implements \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tab\TabInterface
{   

    protected $_assetRepo;

    public function __construct(
       \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository $assetRepo
    ) {
        $this->_assetRepo = $assetRepo;
    }
    /**
     * Prepare form
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareForm()

    {

        $path = $this->_assetRepo->getUrl("vendor_module::importsample/sample.csv");

        $form = $this->_formFactory->create();
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $storemanager = $objectManager->create('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
            'base_fieldset',
            [
                'legend' => __('Import Pincodes'),
                'class'  => 'fieldset-wide'
            ]
        );

        $importdata_script  = $fieldset->addField(
            'file',
            'file',
            [
                'name'  => 'file',
                'label' => __('Upload File'),
                'title' => __('Upload File'),
                'required' => true,
            ]
        );

        $importdata_script->setAfterElementHtml("
        <span id='sample-file-span' ><a id='sample-file-link' href='".$path."'  >Download Sample File</a></span>
        ");

        $this->setForm($form);
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }

    /**
     * Prepare label for tab
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return __('Import Pincodes');
    }

    /**
     * Prepare title for tab
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return $this->getTabLabel();
    }

    /**
     * Can show tab in tabs
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function canShowTab()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Tab is hidden
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isHidden()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

any help on this will be great

**update:-** 
[image]

Comment: have you tried by calling parent constructor as @Msquare answer?

Comment: yeah check the updated question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **Try This**

```
<?php

namespace vendor\module\Block\Adminhtml\Importpincode\Edit\Tab;

class Importpincode extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic implements \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tab\TabInterface
{
    protected $_assetRepo;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository $assetRepo,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_assetRepo = $assetRepo;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare form
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareForm()

    {

        $path = $this->_assetRepo->getUrl("vendor_module::importsample/sample.csv");

        $form = $this->_formFactory->create();
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $storemanager = $objectManager->create('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
            'base_fieldset',
            [
                'legend' => __('Import Pincodes'),
                'class'  => 'fieldset-wide'
            ]
        );

        $importdata_script  = $fieldset->addField(
            'file',
            'file',
            [
                'name'  => 'file',
                'label' => __('Upload File'),
                'title' => __('Upload File'),
                'required' => true,
            ]
        );

        $importdata_script->setAfterElementHtml("
        <span id='sample-file-span' ><a id='sample-file-link' href='".$path."'  >Download Sample File</a></span>
        ");

        $this->setForm($form);
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }

    /**
     * Prepare label for tab
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return __('Import Pincodes');
    }

    /**
     * Prepare title for tab
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return $this->getTabLabel();
    }

    /**
     * Can show tab in tabs
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function canShowTab()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Tab is hidden
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isHidden()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

[image]

**[Update]**

**For UI Component**

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/ui_component**

**import_storelocation_form.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">import_storelocation_form.import_storelocation_form_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">import_storelocation_form.import_storelocation_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">General Information</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data</item>
            <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">import_storelocation_form</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">general_information</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="back" xsi:type="string">VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Storelocator\Edit\Button\Back</item>
            <item name="reset" xsi:type="string">VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Storelocator\Edit\Button\Reset</item>
            <item name="save" xsi:type="string">VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Storelocator\Edit\Button\SaveImportData</item>
        </item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="import_storelocation_form_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">import_storelocation_form_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
              <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                 <item name="submit_url" xsi:type="url" path="*/*/saveimportdata"/>
              </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="general_information">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true"></item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="importfile">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">importfile</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Upload File</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="allowedExtensions" xsi:type="string">csv xls</item>
                    <item name="maxFileSize" xsi:type="number">2097152</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                    <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">VendoreName_ModuleName/file-preview</item>
                    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">importfile</item>
                    <item name="notice" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Allow File Types:-  .csv and .xls</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="storelocator/storelocator/Importupload" >
                            <param name="target_element_id">importfile</param>
                            <param name="type">image</param>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

> **[Click Here to download the source code for the UI component](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1tVconGVbkEyJHrPxbvyW7Fiq5Fge8bSC?usp=sharing)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i got this error. how to fix this:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred when creating object: Rakuten\MemberCard\Block\Adminhtml\Card\Import, Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic::__construct(): Argument #2 ($registry) must be of type Magento\Framework\Registry, array given, called in /var/www/html/rakuten_magento/app/code/Rakuten/MemberCard/Block/Adminhtml/Card/Import.php on line 23

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred when creating object: Rakuten\MemberCard\Block\Adminhtml\Card\Import, Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic::__construct(): Argument #2 ($registry) must be of type Magento\Framework\Registry, array given, called in /var/www/html/rakuten_magento/app/code/Rakuten/MemberCard/Block/Adminhtml/Card/Import.php on line 23
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:56]
#2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/BlockFactory.php:44]
#3 Magento\Framework\View\Element\BlockFactory->createBlock() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php:272]
#4 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->getBlockInstance() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php:252]
#5 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->createBlock() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php:229]
#6 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->generateBlock() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php:134]
#7 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->process() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php:93]
#8 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:365]
#9 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:68]
#10 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->generateElements() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:129]
#11 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php:65]
#12 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:65]
#13 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php:227]
#14 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php:250]
#15 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->getTitle() called at [app/code/Rakuten/MemberCard/Controller/Adminhtml/Card/Import.php:32]
#16 Rakuten\MemberCard\Controller\Adminhtml\Card\Import->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#17 Rakuten\MemberCard\Controller\Adminhtml\Card\Import\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#18 Rakuten\MemberCard\Controller\Adminhtml\Card\Import\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#19 Rakuten\MemberCard\Controller\Adminhtml\Card\Import\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Rakuten/MemberCard/Controller/Adminhtml/Card/Import/Interceptor.php:23]
#20 Rakuten\MemberCard\Controller\Adminhtml\Card\Import\Interceptor->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php:111]
#21 Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php:151]
#22 Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#23 Rakuten\MemberCard\Controller\Adminhtml\Card\Import\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#24 Rakuten\MemberCard\Controller\Adminhtml\Card\Import\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php:145]
#25 Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#26 Rakuten\MemberCard\Controller\Adminhtml\Card\Import\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#27 Rakuten\MemberCard\Controller\Adminhtml\Card\Import\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Rakuten/MemberCard/Controller/Adminhtml/Card/Import/Interceptor.php:32]
#28 Rakuten\MemberCard\Controller\Adminhtml\Card\Import\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:245]
#29 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->getActionResponse() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:212]
#30 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:147]
#31 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#32 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#33 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#34 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:23]
#35 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:116]
#36 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:23]
#37 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:264]
#38 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub/index.php:30]
</pre>
```

Comment: Please upload your code or explain in more detail ?

Comment: Here i wanna know how can i create a templates: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/358376/how-to-create-admin-form-to-upload-file-with-block