# I want to import csv file into multiple tables in magento 2.4.please advice

Tags: magento2, custom, csv, importexport

I am new to magento. I want to import csv file into multiple tables. I created a import.xml, CustomImport.php, RowValidatorInterface.php. After that i created a module, and registraion.php. Even though i am not getting the solution. Please guide me.

Comment: try this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/291799/82670

Comment: thanks for response. But I need for database tables not for image.

Comment: try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/304325/82670

Comment: and you can get table value from like this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/291799/82670

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: @it's helps you ? if yes then i will post it here.

Comment: No sir... i tried its not work for me.