# How to submit a CSV file in admin and how read it in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, csv, file-upload, submit-form

How to submit  a CSV file in admin side  and how read it in Magento2?

Comment: Do you mean how the upload csv files into admin?

Comment: yes i created a Ui from in admin side and i want to add the one more  field for upload csv  file

Comment: can anyone help how i upload csv file and how i read it and which which files i need to create for it

Comment: Dhiren sir i created a Ui from in admin side and i want to add the one more field for upload csv file (Please Answer)

Comment: try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/304325/82670 And Also this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/291799/82670