# How to create a custom field with ui component that has a limit type character?

Tags: magento2

I have a custom admin form, but i do not know how to create 2 differences field
For example: i want to create 2 fields are: employee_number and employee_insurance
But each field has a limit amount of number,
employee_number can only insert number but it must has 6 character like 123456, while
employee_insurance can only insert number but it must has 16 character like 1234567891234567.
How can i make this and i really need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Try This Code**

```
......................................................................
......................................................................
......................................................................

    <field name="employee_number" sortOrder="20" formElement="input">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">employee_number</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <validation>
                <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                <rule name="max_text_length" xsi:type="number">6</rule>
                <rule name="min_text_length" xsi:type="number">6</rule>
            </validation>
            <dataType>text</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Employee Number</label>
            <dataScope>employee_number</dataScope>
        </settings>
    </field>
    <field name="employee_insurance" sortOrder="20" formElement="input">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">Employee Insurance</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <validation>
                <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                <rule name="max_text_length" xsi:type="number">16</rule>
                <rule name="min_text_length" xsi:type="number">16</rule>
            </validation>
            <dataType>text</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Employee Insurance</label>
            <dataScope>employee_insurance</dataScope>
        </settings>
    </field>
......................................................................
......................................................................
......................................................................
```

**Output**: https://prnt.sc/cWyFuPeXUPUN

Comment: Wow that pretty good, hey are you the guy who help answer this question: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/304319/magento2-sample-download-for-custom-import/304325#304325. Could you help me do the same but with ui component

Comment: Sure, i will accept it for you but can you help me with the upload CSV file ?

Comment: @KAITO_3SS Yes sure.

Comment: Wow thank you, you are amazing

Comment: @KAITO_3SS Please download the file and the reference links are shared in that file. I hope this helps you.  https://www.transfernow.net/dl/20220722X9oCm5Hx

Comment: How about you push it on github and you can send me github link. I think that would be much more easier

Comment: @KAITO_3SS Please check I update my answer and please vote up or accept the answer if it helps you. It helps other users to select better answers. https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/304325/82670